# submit form through ajax doesn't work

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, forms, validation

I try to submit a form using ajax. Here is my code:

```
 $BTN.click(function () {
       $.ajax({
          type: 'POST',
          url: "/Record/Edit",
          contentType: 'application/json',
          data: JSON.stringify(data),
          dataType: "json",
        });
 });
```

It works well. But i want to put a validation message to some inputs where the inputs need to be filled. I used has-value in the class. It validates the value when the form is being submitted. So I used this code to submit form. `$('#frmEditCPRRecord').on("submit", function (e) {  });`   It did validates my form, but doesnt submit it.

Comment: try formData here is the documentation https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/FormData/Using_FormData_Objects

Comment: So your problem is validation and not on sending ajax?

Comment: validation works only when using submit function but the form are not submitted. if using button click function, validation does not works but the form is submitted

Comment: I think you should the whole code including the html

Comment: Ensure that you don't have e.preventDefault() inside submit function. It prevents form to submit.

Comment: show us the complete code please including the on submit event listener